# I upgraded node but it still uses the wrong version?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I just ran `brew upgrade node` and it successfully upgraded Node to version >=4, however `node --version` returns the old version:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ node --version
v2.3.0
My-MacBook-Pro:~ me$ brew upgrade node
Error: node 4.1.1 already installed
```

How can I have node use the newest version instead of 2.3.0?

Comment: How are you getting on? have you tried the suggestions in my answer - if so please let me know results.

Comment: What does `which node` say?

Comment: Please can you check the answers provided and mark one correct if you found it helped you. Otherwise, please offer more information..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, did you run:

```
brew update
```

prior to:

```
brew upgrade
```

You could also try linking to the correct version:

```
 brew switch node <version>
```

To see which versions of node homebrew knows about:

```
brew info node
```

If you are on a MAC (as you state) then i would **highly recommend** using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage your node and npm versions - and avoid homebrew for this altogether (especially if support for more than one version is likely). This is the best way to install node on a MAC imho.

Comment: I'd also recommend another addition: [AVN](https://github.com/wbyoung/avn), which works nicely with NVM to automatically switch Node/NPM versions when moving between projects.

Answer (score 1):

`brew unlink node` followed by:

`rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'` followed by:

`brew link --overwrite node`

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to upgrade from Node 0.12.x (io <4.x) to 4.x on OS X is by using the OS X installer from https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.4/node-v4.2.4.pkg.

It automatically symlinks all the required binaries.